# docker-compose Permissions Denied when accessing secrets with authelia

Tags: docker, docker-compose, permissions

I'm starting on a fresh system to deploy a simple docker-compose with swag and authelia.  Previously I've just included my "secrets" in the .env file or directly in authelia configuration file, but I'm trying to employee some best practices here and properly hide the secrets using docker secrets.  However, when starting up my containers, authelia is complaining about permission denied when trying to access.

In the different guides I've looked at, none of them mention permissions on anything other than the secrets directory/files to be root owned and 600 permissions.

My docker directory is in ~/docker with the secrets in ~/docker/secrets.  The secrets directory is root owned with 600 permissions.  My docker directories is owned by uid 1100:1100, and in my docker compose, I have the following docker-compose (slightly edited for public):

```
version: "3.9"

secrets:

  authelia_duo_api_secret_key:
    file: $DOCKERSECRETS/authelia_duo_api_secret_key
  authelia_jwt_secret:
    file: $DOCKERSECRETS/authelia_jwt_secret
  authelia_notifier_smtp_password:
    file: $DOCKERSECRETS/authelia_notifier_smtp_password
  authelia_session_secret:
    file: $DOCKERSECRETS/authelia_session_secret
  authelia_storage_encryption_key:
    file: $DOCKERSECRETS/authelia_storage_encryption_key

x-environment: &default-env
  TZ: $TZ
  PUID: $PUID
  PGID: $PGID

services:

  swag:
    image: ghcr.io/linuxserver/swag
    container_name: swag
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    environment:
      <<: *default-env
      URL: $DOMAINNAME
      SUBDOMAINS: wildcard
      VALIDATION: dns
      CERTPROVIDER: zerossl #optional
      DNSPLUGIN: cloudflare #optional
      EMAIL: <edit>
      DOCKER_MODS: linuxserver/mods:swag-dashboard
    volumes:
      - $DOCKERDIR/appdata/swag:/config
    ports:
      - 443:443
    restart: unless-stopped

  authelia:
    image: ghcr.io/authelia/authelia:latest
    container_name: authelia
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - $DOCKERDIR/appdata/authelia:/config
    user: "1100:1100"
    secrets:
      - authelia_jwt_secret
      - authelia_session_secret
      - authelia_notifier_smtp_password
      - authelia_duo_api_secret_key
      - authelia_storage_encryption_key
    environment:
      AUTHELIA_JWT_SECRET_FILE: /run/secrets/authelia_jwt_secret
      AUTHELIA_SESSION_SECRET_FILE: /run/secrets/authelia_session_secret
      AUTHELIA_NOTIFIER_SMTP_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/authelia_notifier_smtp_password
      AUTHELIA_DUO_API_SECRET_KEY_FILE: /run/secrets/authelia_duo_api_secret_key
      AUTHELIA_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_KEY_FILE: /run/secrets/authelia_storage_encryption_key
```

And the errors I'm getting in my log are:

```
authelia  | 2022-07-28T23:45:05.872818847Z time="2022-07-28T21:15:05-02:30" level=error msg="Configuration: secrets: error loading secret path /run/secrets/authelia_session_secret into key 'session.secret': open /run/secrets/authelia_session_secret: permission denied"
authelia  | 2022-07-28T23:45:05.872844527Z time="2022-07-28T21:15:05-02:30" level=error msg="Configuration: secrets: error loading secret path /run/secrets/authelia_jwt_secret into key 'jwt_secret': open /run/secrets/authelia_jwt_secret: permission denied"
authelia  | 2022-07-28T23:45:05.872847757Z time="2022-07-28T21:15:05-02:30" level=error msg="Configuration: secrets: error loading secret path /run/secrets/authelia_duo_api_secret_key into key 'duo_api.secret_key': open /run/secrets/authelia_duo_api_secret_key: permission denied"
authelia  | 2022-07-28T23:45:05.872850957Z time="2022-07-28T21:15:05-02:30" level=error msg="Configuration: secrets: error loading secret path /run/secrets/authelia_storage_encryption_key into key 'storage.encryption_key': open /run/secrets/authelia_storage_encryption_key: permission denied"
authelia  | 2022-07-28T23:45:05.872853157Z time="2022-07-28T21:15:05-02:30" level=error msg="Configuration: secrets: error loading secret path /run/secrets/authelia_notifier_smtp_password into key 'notifier.smtp.password': open /run/secrets/authelia_notifier_smtp_password: permission denied"
authelia  | 2022-07-28T23:45:05.872855307Z time="2022-07-28T21:15:05-02:30" level=error msg="Configuration: option 'jwt_secret' is required"
authelia  | 2022-07-28T23:45:05.872857277Z time="2022-07-28T21:15:05-02:30" level=error msg="Configuration: duo_api: option 'secret_key' is required when duo is enabled but it is missing"
authelia  | 2022-07-28T23:45:05.872859417Z time="2022-07-28T21:15:05-02:30" level=error msg="Configuration: storage: option 'encryption_key' is required"
authelia  | 2022-07-28T23:45:05.872861397Z time="2022-07-28T21:15:05-02:30" level=fatal msg="Can't continue due to the errors loading the configuration"
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple here.  Does everything have to be run as root in order to access the secrets?  Does that mean changing all my docker directory in my home folder to root, just to hide credentials?  I'm a little confused by this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar permissions errors which i could get rid of by using docker volumes. I oriented myself on this example [here](https://github.com/authelia/authelia/issues/1956).